# erro em consulta de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, query, post, php-7

Tenho a seguinte consulta :

```
<?php
$footerlocal = array(    
    'numberposts' => 2, 
    'post_type' => 'page',       
    'meta_query' => array( 
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array(  'key' => 'zona', 'value' => '"norte"',  'compare' => 'LIKE'),
        array( 'key' => 'zona', 'value' => '"sul"', 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
        array( 'key' => 'zona',  'value' => '"leste"', 'compare' => 'LIKE'  ),
        array( 'key' => 'zona', 'value' => '"oeste"',  'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
      )
 );
?>
```

bom, no meta_query tem algum erro, pois sempre que excluo, a listagem de posts aparece...se uso o meta_query para filtrar, ele não retorna nada, mas eu vi algumas páginas que contém conteúdo compatível para ser listada o que pode ser feito para tornar esses parâmetros, corretos??
obrigado a todos!!
bom dia!!!

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 0):

1- Para listar os posts do wordpress, vc precisa colocar o valor do 'post_type' como 'post', dessa forma que vc fez: 'post_type' => 'page', está tentando consultar as páginas criadas.

2- numberposts é usado para consultar x quantidade de posts, enquanto posts_per_page é usado para listar um número x de post por página, não sei se foi proposital ou vc se confundiu, mas acredito que vale a pena esclarecer aqui.

3- Dessa forma que eu fiz vai mostrar 2 posts que o valor do campo 'zona', seja igual a um dos valores: norte', 'sul', 'leste', 'oeste', segue o codigo:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'zona',
        'value'   => array( 'norte', 'sul', 'leste', 'oeste')
        'compare' => 'IN',
    )
),
```

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );